# Trying to save application settings crashes the application. What am i doing wrong?

Tags: c#, .net, application-settings, applicationsettingsbase

I've been ready up on and implementing [Application settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/managing-application-settings-dotnet?view=vs-2022&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(msvse_settingsdesigner.Err.NameBlank)%26rd%3Dtrue) however I'm running into a problem.

I'm promting the user to input a token for a discord bot. Which works fine if I don't call the .Save() method. but as soon as I do I get "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationUserLevel' to type 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationFileMap'." The only related thing I was able to find is https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/25748 which seems to be resolved.What am i doing wrong?

For clarity this is the code I'm using

```
 if(DiscordQuery.Default.BotToken == "")
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"[REQUEST] {DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss")} Please input your bot token");
            string token = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(token);
            DiscordQuery.Default.BotToken = token;
            DiscordQuery.Default.Save();
        }
```

And the xml copy of the .settings file (just to be sure noone things I accidentally set the scope to application). If it matters I'm using .net 7.0 and building for win-x86

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<SettingsFile xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2004/01/settings" CurrentProfile="(Default)" GeneratedClassNamespace="DiscordQueryBot" GeneratedClassName="DiscordQuery">
  <Profiles />
  <Settings>
    <Setting Name="BotToken" Type="System.String" Scope="User">
      <Value Profile="(Default)" />
    </Setting>
    <Setting Name="EmbedDescriptions" Type="System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection" Scope="User">
      <Value Profile="(Default)" />
    </Setting>
  </Settings>
</SettingsFile>
```